# Android PathMeausure.getSegment()

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have to implement hand writing of Japanese symbols. 
I have a pth of symbol. It works good when i simply call canvas.drawPath().

At first I am trying to draw all path from PathMeausure.

Drawing without PathMeausre works  fine:

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

[image: Normal image]

And drawing of path after PathMeasure doesn't work

```
        mTempPath.reset();
        mPathMeasure.setPath(mPath, false);
        mPathMeasure.getSegment(0, mPathMeasure.getLength(), mTempPath, true);
        mTempPath.rLineTo(0, 0); //Hack from developers.anroid.com
        canvas.drawPath(mTempPath, mPaint);
```

[image: Bad image]

**So it draws only first part of path**

**How can i fix it ?**

Comment: Since there is not single continuous path there are multiple one so you need to record all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have a single continuos path. Try something like this:

```
    mTempPath.reset();
    mPathMeasure.setPath(mPath, false);

do{
    mPathMeasure.getSegment(0, mPathMeasure.getLength(), mTempPath, true);
    mTempPath.rLineTo(0, 0); 
    canvas.drawPath(mTempPath, mPaint);
}while(pm.nextContour());
```

Comment: Yes, i agree that i have more than one parts of path. And as i found in doc, there is no way to measure multiple path as solid one. OK, i will try to separate it.

Comment: I found that getLength() returns  different value depends on what is the  current contour in measure. So i can calculate it and handle. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, mTempPath.rLineTo(0, 0);  works like a charm. In nougat is not necessary.